# Flagging an answer while reviewing outside of review does not update review page

Tags: support

Just right now I was reviewing a first post, an answer.  In such cases, I usually like to open the entire question in a new tab so that I can view the answer in relation to the question and the other answers.  Well, in this new tab, I flagged the answer which was obviously not an answer.  When I returned to the review page, the No Action Needed was still highlighted.  As some reviews are "tests" for obviously bad posts, I don't want to do No Action Needed because it could count against me.  Is there some way we can adjust the process so that a reviewer does not get stuck like this?

Comment: Perhaps reloading would enable "I'm Done"?

Comment: I just had another case where the same idea applied, and yes reload worked.  I guess this is the general approach to take.